# Class already registered as subclass (module structure for addon)

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am working on creating an addon and I have a main `__init__.py` file and then I have a another file we will call `utils.py`. `__init__` registers all the classes in `utils` by `import utils` and then `bpy.utils.register_class(utils.CLASS)`, it has several classes and that file registers them all.

If you run the file once it works fine, but if you run it again it gives the error that the class is already registered as a subclass.

`utils` contains a `bpy.types.Panel` and `bpy.types.Operator` class. It is almost like the `bpy.utils.unregister_class(utils.CLASS)` isn't working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace all calls to `bpy.utils.register_class(...)` by a single call to

```
bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
```

and all calls to `bpy.utils.unregister_class(...)` by a single

```
bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
```

You won't have to (un-)register single classes ever again and your error should no longer occur. Do it in `__init__.py` only and import all module files from here (`from . import ...`).

Note that the order of class definitions may matter, e.g. if you use a custom property group class in an operator (the code of the property group class needs to be above the class definition of the operator).

Comment: so my import would say `from . import utils` in my `__init__.py` file, or are you saying leave that all out. If I put the import code as I just did I get a `Parent Module "" not found, can't import` error, if I leave out that line it runs, but doesn't register the classes in the second file, same thing happens if I do `from .utils import *`

Comment: I added a link to an example addon comprised of 3 files to show how to import properly with reload support.

Comment: I added what you said, and I am still getting that same error. I attached my files to my original post.

Comment: Installed and enabled your addon, also refreshed with `F8`, and there is no error. Did you restart Blender after the changes? Because you sometimes need to, a refresh/reload is not enough.

Comment: I believe I did, does it work for you from the text editor as well?

Comment: No, of course it doesn't, you can't run individual files of addons in the text editor (without issues).

Comment: Ok, I thought that I had heard that you couldn't run them from the text editor, but I wasn't certain. I tried installing the addon and it doesn't work for me, but I have these files not in `2.72/addons` folder. I will put them in there are try again.

Comment: that worked for me, just one question. When I went to remove the addon the `Remove` option wasn't there. Any ideas?

Comment: only user addons show a remove button, determined by the file path. On Windows, user addons are located in `%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\addons`

Comment: Looks like `register_module` and `unregister_module` functions no longer exist. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59926247/2981429

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you load the same add on multiple times. Try removing the add on. close the blender. Relaunch the blender and now try adding the add on. Worked for me.