# How to find what text file is open in text editor

Tags: python, scripting, text-editor

I was wondering how to find which text file is open in the text editor. I know you can find a list of the loaded files via `bpy.data.texts`, but I can't seem to find a way to find the one that is being edited currently.

Comment: For a solution to a similar problem that does not depend on UI state, check out http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35781/how-do-i-import-functions-from-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-the-file-that-is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active text datablocks are referenced by TextEditor spaces:

[bpy.types.SpaceTextEditor.text](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72b_release/bpy.types.SpaceTextEditor.html?highlight=spacetexteditor#bpy.types.SpaceTextEditor.text)

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'TEXT_EDITOR':
        space = area.spaces.active
        print(repr(space.text))

# Example output with one visible text editor:
# bpy.data.texts['ui_menu_simple.py']
```

Comment: works great! Thanks, also, could you take another look at this thread http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18072/class-already-registered-as-subclass