# how install Batch Transform in v 2.76b?

Tags: 3d-view, add-on, blend-files

I've downloaded the zip folder from [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/BatchTransforms#Batch_Transforms), unziped but there are a lot of py files? which of them I have to select in order to install all its functionalities?. I've tried to pick one by one, but nothing new appears in the addons list of blender 3D view.

Comment: See if this Question helps: [Installing an addon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1688/2217)

Comment: thanks. Now, I deleted the addon and I've followed the suggestion in the acepted answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19168 and effectively the addon (py filed plus dairin0d folder) are in the config/blender/2.76/scripts/addons  directory BUT it doesn't appear in the addon list in the testing category for 3D View yet , sh***

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just installed this particular addon to make certain of the correct process. The issue is the way the addon was packaged (blender's "install from file" is looking for the files to be in a set hierarchy and order). You can delete any files you have from previous attempts at installing the addon, as blender will never even look for them.
However getting the addon to run is not hard.

1. Manually unzip the [download](https://github.com/dairin0d/transform-utils/releases/download/v0.4.8/space_view3d_transform_utils.zip) (which you already have), found on the [wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/BatchTransforms#Batch_Transforms) or on the [releases](https://github.com/dairin0d/transform-utils/releases) page, into a folder called exactly "*space_view3d_transform_utils*" without the quotes. (windows will by default unzip to a new folder with this name.)
2. Copy that new folder "*space_view3d_transform_utils*" into blender's addon directory. Here is the correct path to the user addon folder on windows and linux.

   Windows:

   > %APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons

   Linux:

   > $HOME/.config/blender/2.76/scripts/addons
3. Open up blender and go to the Addons tab of the *User Preferences*. Search for "batch" and enable the addon called "3D View: Batch Transforms (Transform Utils)."

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39745/2217) elaborates on why some zipped addons do not install.