# multiple file package changes in blender 2.7?

Tags: python, add-on, packed-data

In fact I want to pack many add-ons.

I was using some "standard" `__init__.py` [check](https://github.com/YHOYO/mesh_doshape_tools/blob/master/__init__.py)

but in reality this does not work, then I tried the example of [wiki blender](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Multi-File_packages) changing the deprecated `import imp` to`of importlib import reload` but this example does not work either!

I looked for some reference in [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/index.html) but I do not get anything

also the CoDEManX code from [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18072/class-already-registered-as-subclass-module-structure-for-addon/18075#18075) is not avalaible,... then ...

**what is the current way of packaging multiple files?**

Comment: Do you mean in 2.8. Pretty sure I read that  `bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)` is getting ditched.  As for how to handle multifile addons, blender ships with a number of them, checkout their source.  Here's something I was looking at a while back to package addons https://gist.github.com/batFINGER/4eee7c1a03746c65f2611c70a9f2e2ba

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for sharing. But how use that with custom icons?...

Comment: Please update the question to be either about "packed data" (i.e. images and other assets being packed inside the blend file) or about "multi-file packages" (i.e. Python packages that consist of a directory with multiple `.py` files in them).

Answer (score 1):

I made the example of [wiki blender](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Multi-File_packages) with a little change. It seems to work well.
Version 2.79

```
# To support reload properly, try to access a package var, 
# if it's there, reload everything
if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib
    if 'simple_obj_import' in locals():
        importlib.reload(simple_obj_import)
    if 'simple_obj_export' in locals():
        importlib.reload(simple_obj_export)

import bpy
from bpy.props import *
#from io_utils import ExportHelper, ImportHelper
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper, ImportHelper
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer. I didn't use that  wiki. I will try. Can you extend the answer  using custom icons?

Comment: Be sure to also assign the returned value, so `simple_obj_import = importlib.reload(simple_obj_import)`; without that you could still have a reference to the old import.